# How to randomly split image dataset while using ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

Supposed having a directory-based structured image training-set for a classification problem as following:

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......a_image_1.jpg
......a_image_2.jpg
...class_b/
......b_image_1.jpg
......b_image_2.jpg
```

I would like to randomly split the training-set into multiple subsets (preferably in diverse sizes) to be fed to multiple deep learning models of a **bagging ensemble**. The library that is used to read the dataset is `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`.

I am aware that `flow_from_directory()` is able to split the training set into two desired subsets of training and validation through setting `validation_split` attribute as `True`. That is, however, not enough. I need to randomly split my training set into multiple subsets.

---

P.S.: One way I can think of is to manually shuffling the content of each subdirectory and then dividing the images into some separate directories and calling `flow_from_directory()` separately for each one. Yet, I am not quite sure if this is a practical solution.

Comment: tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(shuffle=True) ?

Comment: @HSa It's not going to split the dataset for me. Wished this method had some sort of input like `split=5` to clip the whole dataset into multiple subsets.

Comment: If you use `tf.data` API then you can achieve this lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe. It is cumbersome but can be done. The code below will read in your image data and produce a train_df, a test_df and a valid_df. You can loop through through this function and create different dataset by setting tr_split, vsplit and random_ste to different values each time to produce unique data sets. You can then produce generators for each unique data frame sets and use those as input to model.fit.

```
def preprocess (sdir, trsplit, random_seed):    
    for category in ['train', 'test']:
        filepaths=[]
        labels=[]
        catpath=os.path.join(sdir, category)
        classlist=os.listdir(catpath)
        for klass in classlist:
            classpath=os.path.join(catpath,klass)
            flist=os.listdir(classpath)
            for f in flist:
                fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)
                filepaths.append(fpath)
                labels.append(klass)
        Fseries=pd.Series(filepaths, name='filepaths')
        Lseries=pd.Series(labels, name='labels')
        if category == 'train':
            df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)
        else:
            test_df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)       
    # split df into train_df and test_df 
    strat=df['labels']    
    train_df, valid_df=train_test_split(df, train_size=trsplit, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed, stratify=strat)    
    print('train_df length: ', len(train_df), '  test_df length: ',len(test_df), '  valid_df length: ', len(valid_df))
    print(train_df['labels'].value_counts())
    return train_df, test_df, valid_df
```

An example of calling the function is shown in the code below

```
sdir=r'C:\Temp\malig'
random_seed =123
tr_split=.8
train_df, test_df, valid_df= preprocess(sdir, tr_split, random_seed)
```

The resulting output will be

```
train_df length:  2109   test_df length:  660   valid_df length:  528
benign       1152
malignant     957
Name: labels, dtype: int64
```

Now call this function as many times as you wish, each time changing the random_seed
and/or the values of tr_split  to create different train and valid data frames. Then create the generators with the code below

```
img_size=(224,224)
channels=3
batch_size=30
img_shape=(img_size[0], img_size[1], channels)
length=len(test_df)
test_batch_size=sorted([int(length/n) for n in range(1,length+1) if length % n ==0 and length/n<=80],reverse=True)[0]  
test_steps=int(length/test_batch_size)
print ( 'test batch size: ' ,test_batch_size, '  test steps: ', test_steps)
def scalar(img):    
    return img  # EfficientNet expects pixelsin range 0 to 255 so no scaling is required
trgen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=scalar, horizontal_flip=True)
tvgen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=scalar)
train_gen=trgen.flow_from_dataframe( train_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
test_gen=tvgen.flow_from_dataframe( test_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=False, batch_size=test_batch_size)

valid_gen=tvgen.flow_from_dataframe( valid_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
classes=list(train_gen.class_indices.keys())
class_count=len(classes)
train_steps=int(np.ceil(len(train_gen.labels)/batch_size))
```

The resulting output should show

```
test batch size:  66   test steps:  10
Found 2109 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.
Found 660 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.
Found 528 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.
```

Now build your model, then run model.fit using these generators

Comment: Could you please provide an example for calling the function? I'm getting `ValueError` from `train_df, dummy_df=train_test_split(...)`. In my case, I am trying to split [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/fanconic/skin-cancer-malignant-vs-benign) which has only two classes. Running `train_df, test_df, valid_df = preprocess('./skin-cancer/', 0.8, 0.2, 2)` leads to `ValueError: The test_size = 2 should be greater or equal to the number of classes = 3`.

Comment: I went and downloaded the dataset. I did not know there was both a train and test directory. See modified answer which I tested and it works. The dataset is stored in directory sdir.